# Python-XMPP - Iterate the IQ stanza items

Tags: python, python-2.7, xmpp

I'm using python-xmpp to connect to gtalk. I'm receiving the responses and I can send and receive a message to a specific user/email. I am looking for a way to iterate over the `IQ` items so that I can get the `jid` and `name` attribute for each item.
The IQ stanza is of the form:

```
<iq to="example@gmail.com/test" id="3" type="result">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
<item jid="test2@example.com" subscription="both" name="ABCD"/>
<item jid="test2@example.com" subscription="both" name="EFGH"/>
.
.
</query>
</iq>
```

I'd also like to update the user on receiving `<presence>` stanza. I'm guessing I should use a callback, like I am doing now to handle receiving of messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the node can be parsed as any xml.
This is what solved my problem:

```
query_node=iq_node.getQueryChildren()
for node in query_node:
    print node.getAttr("name")
```

`iq_node` is the `xmpp.protocol.Iq` object and every `node` is a `xmpp.simplexml.Node` object